# Make a get api that returns a BLOB .net core (EF)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a database with a table that has an id and a BLOB.
What i want is to get the blob and essentially stream it to the client, 
and not retrieve it in memory. That is because the blob can be really big (100s of MB).

I have almost achieved this using SQLdataReader.
Doing this, when i make a get request, it starts downloading immediately, and there is no overhead on memory. This was using .net core 2.2
However, when I switched to .net core 3.1, now it doesn't work, and the memory gets filled up with 100s of megabytes. I would also like to achieve the same result using entity framework, but till now i haven't found any good online resources.

Here is the code I have up until now.

```
[HttpGet]
    public  IEnumerable<Byte[]> GetStreaming()
    {

        var header = Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        System.Console.WriteLine(header);

        string connectionString = "Data Source=myPc\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=admin";

        //----------------------
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("exec getBlob", connection);

        SqlTransaction tran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        command.Transaction = tran;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[5000000];
        long position = 0;
        long bytesRead = 5000000;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
        {
            reader.Read();
            reader.GetBytes(0, position, null, 0, 5000000);
            while (bytesRead == 5000000)
            {
                // Get the pointer for file
                bytesRead = reader.GetBytes(0, position, buffer, 0, 5000000);
                position += bytesRead;
                yield return buffer;

                // Create the SqlFileStream

            }

        }

    }
```

I've tried just doing it like this

```
        public  IEnumerable<byte[]> DownloadFile()
    {

        yield return  context.t_noFs.Where(u => u.Id == 1)
            .Select(u => u.dat).
            FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

and while this does return a value, it doesn't have the desired effect and fills the memory up.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in your case would be to use streams.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public  FileStreamResult GetStreaming()
{
    var header = Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
    System.Console.WriteLine(header);

    string connectionString = "Data Source=myPc\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=admin";

    //----------------------
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("exec getBlob", connection);

    SqlTransaction tran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    command.Transaction = tran;
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
    var blobStream = reader.GetStream(0);

    return new FileStreamResult(blobStream, "application/x-binary")
    {
         FileDownloadName = "your file name"
    };
}
```

Comment: im getting an internal server error with this. 
Is there some other information that I didn't provide that could be the culprit to this problem? does this require the latest versions of .net core and EF?

Comment: What is the exact exception you are getting?

Comment: It said that it couldn't access disposed object.
I removed the using () from around the SqlDataReader and now it downloaded the file

Comment: Might be, I didn't test it it's just an example of how it should be used. But I will update it.

Comment: Do you know if this is achievable with Entity framework?

Comment: You need to delay Dispose() on the SqlDataReader and SqlConnection until the end of the request.  Add `Response.RegisterForDispose(reader);` and     `Response.RegisterForDispose(connection);`  Disposing them early will cause an error, and not disposing them will cause a connection leak.